# How to find which module to require for a racket symbol?

Tags: racket

*When encountering an unbound identifier error for a racket symbol, how should one find out which module to require for the symbol?*

For example, I encountered the following error while execute a racket file (as of 8.6):

```
....rkt:39:17: symbol=?: reference to an unbound identifier
;   at phase: 1; the transformer environment
```

I tried `(help symbol=?)`, which correctly led me to its documentation page, on "Section 4.2 Booleans". But how can I tell which module to import so that I can have `symbol=?`?

I tried

```
(require (for-meta 1 racket/base))
```

but the error remains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get that information from [DrRacket Docs](https://docs.racket-lang.org)- when you search for any symbol, you will see a list of packages/ libraries that provide it.

Look at the [results for symbol=?](https://docs.racket-lang.org/search/index.html?q=symbol%3D%3F). The most straightforward solution is to use `#lang racket` (at the beginning of the code) or `(require racket/bool)`.

This is even written in "Section 4.2 Booleans"- there are symbols `boolean?`, `not` and `immutable?`, followed by "4.2.1 Boolean Aliases":

*(require racket/bool)

package: base
The bindings documented in this section are provided by the racket/bool and racket libraries, but not racket/base.*